# Char length is greater than the real length

Tags: mysql, char, distinct, string-length

I'm loading data in a MySQL database, but I've a problem, I have just loaded all data but the field Buyer is working bad:

`SELECT  CHAR_length(TRIM(BUYER)) AS L, BUYER
 FROM ST_REQ`

And the result is:

`17|Viccaro Fabrizio`

I will copy paste the BUYER:
`Viccaro Fabrizio`--> It has only 16 characters.

Any idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: The Table encoding/charset/collation can be different from the onde user on results. Some chars can became 'invisible'

Answer (score 0):

mysql trim only trimming both end spaces only. and CHAR_length adding spaces also.

> mysql> insert into ContactInformation (CONTACT_EMAIL,FIRSTNAME) values ("arunkumar.m@xxxxxx.com","arun kumar");
>   Query OK, 1 row affected, 3 warnings (0.01 sec)

```
mysql> SELECT  CHAR_length(TRIM(FIRSTNAME)),FIRSTNAME from ContactInformation;
 +------------------------------+------------+
 | CHAR_length(TRIM(FIRSTNAME)) | FIRSTNAME  |
 +------------------------------+------------+
 |                           10 | arun kumar |
 +------------------------------+------------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```